# NOAA data and writing a csv file

Tags: csv

I am trying to create a csv file from NOAA data from their http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/obhistory/PAFA.html.

At the moment, I am having problems writing the csv file.

```
import urllib2 as urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import localtime, strftime
import csv
url = 'http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/obhistory/PAFA.html'
file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_pointer)

table = soup('table')[3]
table_rows = table.findAll('tr')
row_count = 0
for table_row in table_rows:
row_count += 1
if row_count < 4:
 continue

date = table_row('td')[0].contents[0]
time = table_row('td')[1].contents[0]
wind = table_row('td')[2].contents[0]

print date, time, wind
with open("/home/eyalak/Documents/weather/weather.csv", "wb") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
print date, time, wind
writer.writerow( ('Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3') )
writer.writerow(str(time)+str(wind)+str(date)+'\n')
 if row_count == 74:
  print "74"
```

The printed result is fine, it is the file that is not. I get:

```
Title   1,Title 2,Title 3
0,5,:,5,3,C,a,l,m,0,8,"
```

The problems in the csv file created are: 1. The title is broken into the wrong columns;column 2, has "1,Title" versus "title 2" 2. The data is comma delineated in the wrong places 3. As The script writes new lines it over writes on the previous one, instead of appending from the bottom. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As far as overwriting rows try opening the file with the 'a' (append) option rather than 'wb'.  As far as fixing the comma delineation try to encapsulate each string in square brackets.  Take a look at the two examples here to see the difference:

```
import csv

text = 'This is a string'

with open('test.csv','a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(text)
```

This creates a csv whose first row is each letter of text is separated by a comma.  Alternatively,

```
import csv

text = 'This is a string'

with open('test.csv','a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([text])
```

This will create a csv file whose first row contains only one item that is text and there is no comma separating the characters.